# How to Get the Current URL Adress From cef Browser c# winforms

Tags: c#, cefsharp

How can i get The current Url from cef browser c# winforms . i want URL to be displayed in  textBox1 in Form1 Whenver browser loads a URL ( visit a website )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current URL from the CEF browser in a C# WinForms project, you need to add these things in your code:

1. Create an Address Changed Event for the browser.
2. Put this code in the:

   ```
   private void chromiumWebBrowser1_AddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
   ```

   ```
   string url = e.Address;
   textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = url));
   ```

For Example:

```
private void chromiumWebBrowser1_AddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string url = e.Address;
    textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = url));
}
```

In the above example, we see that whenever the browser loads a URL, it triggers the address change event and, inside the event, we are getting the URL using the `Invoke` method.

if any futher questions reply to this ANSWER

Regards Adit